# Why is ref local assignment required to be an identity conversion?

Tags: c#, cil, ref

There is a restriction on ref locals and ref returns, that there must exist an identity conversion between the type of the local/return and the actual value. So this is illegal:

```cs
class Base { }

class Derived : Base { }

class C
{
    private Derived _derived = new Derived();

    public ref Base GetRef() => ref _derived;
}
```

But since there's an identity conversion between `dynamic` and `object` this would be legal:

```cs
class C
{
    private object _object = new object();

    public ref dynamic GetRef() => ref _object;
}
```

So the question is, what is the reason behind this restriction? All I can presume is that IL has no conversions between refs at all, so if your method returns `Base&` it has to return exactly that, because you cannot convert between `Derived&` and `Base&`. But *why* can't you? Is it

1. impossible to do so, because it will break something with the type system down the line; or
2. it is theoretically possible, but just way too complicated to implement?

Comment: Actually, `dynamic` **is** `object`, with additional metadata.

Comment: The reason why the first isn't allowed is that if it were, the caller would be able to stuff any object reference into the thing it got back, as long as that thing is a `Base` or derives from it. However, the variable it refers to requires that the thing that is stuffed into it is a `Derived` or derives from it.

Comment: `C c = new C(); c.GetRef() = new Base();`

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this mention of "identity conversion"?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yeah, down on IL there's no such thing as a dynamic so that's also an `Object&`. The reason you gave is simple and sound, I feel kinda dumb for not seeing that.

Comment: An identity conversion is defined in the [C# spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions) as a conversion from the type to itself, conversion between `dynamic` and `object` and conversion between generic types where there exists an identity conversion for each type parameter (so `List<dynamic>` = `List<object>`). Since there's no spec for ref locals (not that I know of), I assumed that it accepts all identity conversions experimentally.